# Good bound for $\sum_{p\mid n}\frac{1}{p}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I am trying to get a good asymptotic bound for $$\sum_{\substack{p\mid n\\ \text{$p$ prime}}}\frac{1}{p}.$$ One way I can think of is $$\sum_{p\mid n}\frac1p\leqslant \sum_{p\leqslant n}\frac{1}{p} \ll \log\log n,$$ by  Mertens' theorem.
Can we do better?

As a follow-up question, if you see a sum like this, is there a way to intuitively guess how large it could be?  Thanks!

Comment: The sum heavily depends on the prime factorization of $n$

Comment: It's hard to say how big this is since if $n$ is a large prime, the value differs widely from when $n$ is highly composite (say a large factorial). Perhaps you'd be better off looking at its average value.

Comment: The OP asks for an asymptotic _bound_, not an asymptotic limit. So the question is a good one.

Comment: There is a bound for the number for divisors of n, which is closer to what you want https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/the-divisor-bound/ 
It's $\exp (O (\frac{\log (n)}{\log \log (n)}) $

Comment: The sum has peaks when $n$ is a [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial).

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I would say 1/2

Comment: For $n=4$, is this $\frac12$ or $1$? I'm guessing $\frac12$. (Reposting accidentally deleted comment.)

Comment: @TonyK Surely can we find an asymptotic bound but this bound is of very little merit because many $n$ give very small positive values and on the other hand arbitarily large values occur.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 You are right because every prime factor occurs only once in the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{p|n} 1/p \le \sum_{p| \prod_{q\le k_n} q}1/p= \sum_{p\le O(\log n)} 1/p= O(\log\log\log n)$$

where $\prod_{q\le k_n} q$ is the least primorial $\ge n$:

$\prod_{q\le k_n} q\ge \exp(k_n/10)$ gives $k_n\le 10\log(n)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just thought I would ask if the first equality should actually be an inequality, although that does not affect the final result (also, you are summing 1/p, not p, right?). In addition, the second bound ($\displaystyle \prod_{q\leq k_n}q\ge \exp(k_n/2)$) follows by taking log of the LHS and using the prime number theorem, right?

Comment: Which one you think is an equality? Yes I corrected $1/p$. Yes but the PNT is not needed, use that $\prod_{p\in (n,2n)}\log p\le \log {2n\choose n}$

Answer (score 1):

Similar to how Gronwall deduced

$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}{\sigma(n)\over e^\gamma n\log\log n}=1
$$

We consider defining $a_n$ such that

$$
\prod_{p\le p_{a_n}}p\le n\le\prod_{p\le p_{a_n+1}}p
$$

Taking logarithms gives

$$
{\vartheta(p_{a_n})\over p_{a_n}}\le{\log n\over p_{a_n}}\le{p_{a_n+1}\over p_m}\cdot{\vartheta(p_{a_n+1})\over p_{a_n+1}}
$$

Now, due to prime number theorem we have $p_n\sim p_{n+1}$ and $\vartheta(x)\sim x$, so that

$$
\log n\sim p_{a_n}\tag1
$$

With these priliminaries, we can begin working on the problem

$$
\sum_{p|n}\frac1p\le\sum_{p\le p_{a_n}}\frac1p=\log\log p_{a_n}+\mathcal O(1)
$$

By (1), we also see that

$$
\sum_{p\le p_{a_n}}\frac1p\sim\log\log\log n
$$

To see how tight this bound is, we set

$$
n_k=(p_1p_2\cdots p_k)^{\lfloor\log p_k\rfloor}
$$

so that

$$
\log n_k=\lfloor\log p_k\rfloor\vartheta(p_k)\sim p_k\log p_k
$$

and

$$
\log\log n_k\sim\log p_k
$$

Plugging these into the original formula, we get

$$
\sum_{p|n}\frac1p=\sum_{p\le p_k}\frac1p\sim\log\log p_k\sim\log\log\log n
$$

Therefore, $\log\log\log n$ is not only an upper bound for $\sum_{p|n}\frac1p$, but also a maximal order for $\sum_{p|n}\frac1p$:

$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}{1\over\log\log\log n}\sum_{p|n}\frac1p=1
$$